# passing data between firstviewcontroller's table view and secondviewcontroller of tabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I want to do pass selected row text from first tab's table view to second tab's view label. I try this but it not work :S stringdir is a nsstring

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
// ...
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
detailViewController.stringdir= [ws2.CustomerName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
NSLog(@"şişşşt %@ ", detailViewController.stringdir);

[detailViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move detailViewController.stringdir = ... before you push the view controller to nav controller stack.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
SecondViewController *detailViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

detailViewController.stringdir= [ws2.CustomerName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
NSLog(@"şişşşt %@ ", detailViewController.stringdir);

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

[detailViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Does NSLog print it correctly as expected. How did you set your stringdir property in SecondViewController

Comment: in secondViewController viewDidLoad enyakinfirma.text = stringdir; and I can see detailViewController.stringdir's value with nslog. it is which I selected.

Comment: what can I do now? Is there anybody know this problem?? please help me!!

Comment: What do you see when you NSLog stringdir in second view controller viewDidLoad. Whats the property you have set to stringdir in SecondViewController ? is it retain or copy or assign ?

Comment: in second view controller's I see the nsstring is null - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 enyakinfirma.text = stringdir;
    NSLog(@"hayret %@",stringdir);
} In secondViewController.h @property(nonatomic,assign)NSString *stringdir;

Comment: in secondViewController stringdir is null because I can not pushing viewcontroller and passing data to stringdir.

Comment: change the property to retain or copy and access your property using self.stringdir

Comment: I did your solve but still not work. I changed it in secondViewController.h like @property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *stringdir; and secondViewController.m viewDidLoad { ..     enyakinfirma.text = self.stringdir;
}